# If $I$ is finitely generated, $R/I$ and $R/J$ are Artinian rings. Then, $R/IJ$ is Artinian

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $I,J$ ideals of $R$. Suppose that $I$ is finitely generated, $R/I$ and $R/J$ are Artinian rings. I'm trying to proof that $R/IJ$ is also an Artinian ring.

My idea: Consider the exact sequence
$$ 0 \to I/IJ \overset{i}{\rightarrow} R/IJ \overset{p}{\rightarrow} R/I \to 0 , $$

where $i$ is the inclusion and $p: R/IJ \to \frac{R/IJ}{I/IJ} \simeq R/I$ the canonical projection. So we have to see that $I/IJ$ and $R/I$ are $R/IJ-$Artinian modules.What implies in $R/IJ$ be Artinian.

I think that $I/IJ$ is Artinian as $R/IJ-$module since $I$ is finitely generated. But I'm not sure about it.

The part that $R/I$ is Artinian as $R/IJ-$module I couldn't see either.

Help?

Comment: It is given that $R/I$ is an Artinian $R$-module, right? But $IJ$ is in the kernel of this module, it acts as $0$ on it. Hence it is Artinian as $R/IJ$-module as well. We also have $I/IJ$ is a finitely generated module over $R/J$, which is an Artinian ring. Hence $I/IJ$ is also Artinian $R/J$-module,  and as before, it is an Artinian $R/IJ$-module.

Comment: Hi: for future reference, in English the adjective is "Artinian" not "Arthinian."

Comment: Indeed, it is named after Emil Artin, an Austrian mathematician. https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_Artin

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as the map $R \to R/I$ is surjective, $R/I$ submodules of any $R/I$ module $M$ are the same as $R$ submodules, so $M$ being an Artinian $R/I$ module is equivlant to being an Artinian $R$ module. Similarly for $R/J$ and $R/IJ$

In the exact sequence

$0 \to I/IJ \overset{i}{\rightarrow} R/IJ \overset{p}{\rightarrow} R/I \to 0$

$R/I$ is an Artinian $R$ module, as $R/I$ is an Artinian module over itself.

$I/IJ$ is a finitely generated module over $R/J$ which is an Artinian ring, so it is an Artinian $R/J$ module, thus also an Artinian $R$ module.

So by exactness, we get that $R/IJ$ is an Artinian $R$ module, hence an Artinian $R/IJ$ module, i.e. an Artinian ring.